# GLYPHICONS search icon code required

Tags: javascript, html, css

hi i am using following links to display the search bar icon

```
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but i implement this css and javascript it change my html padding and margins.
So any one knows teh code of search icon

the html code following which is using the above link

```
<div id="search_bar">
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" />
      <button type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

these links

Comment: Which links exactly?

Comment: Just use fontAwesome instead.

Comment: @ChrisG That is not the *solution*. The OP of course didn't ask for alternatives!

Comment: Providing front end code in snippets is a good practice, by the way.

Comment: @MrigankPawagi That's why I posted it as comment and not as answer....

Comment: Your code is perfectly working, check the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/uzjstqfk/

Comment: What are you even saying? Please be more clear! What links do You want?

Comment: OP wants *just* the search icon, not all of Bootstrap (because it screws with his look and layout). READ.

Comment: Maybe try this: http://glyphicons.com/

Comment: hi when i add the javascript and css in my project the template padding and margin look like unprofessional. Template is just like destroyed.

Comment: i just need the search icon code to display the search bar in my project. can tell send the CSS and HTML code of that so i just put that code in my project and run my code

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}

.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.glyphicon-search:before {
  content: "\e003";
}
```

```html
<div id="search_bar">
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" />
      <button type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```